# Error: /c/Users/USER/AppData/Local/atom/bin/../app-1.36.1/resources/cli/atom.sh: line 23: cmd.exe: command not found

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, git-bash

I'm using windows 64-bit machine and trying to open Atom editor through git bash. Previously I have added the environment variable as follows,[image]

Then I have tried `$ atom`command in my git bash and following error occurs,

> /c/Users/USER/AppData/Local/atom/bin/../app-1.36.1/resources/cli/atom.sh: line 23: cmd.exe: command not found

[image]

Please, can anyone help me with this?

PS: Atom version is `1.36.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is illustrated by [atom/atom issue 17034](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/17034):

> It looks like you've **modified your $PATH to remove the Microsoft core paths**... including the one that specifies where `cmd.exe` is located.
> If you fix that things should start working again.

Try launching Atom from a CMD session, where you would type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

set PATH=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\atom\bin;%PATH%
```

(Replace '`USER`' by your Windows account name)

From there: type `bash` to enter in  bash session, and check that the command `atom` does launch Atom.