# When I Git commit, cmd.exe not found

Tags: git, atom-editor, commit, git-commit

Quite new to git, so if i made any obvious mistakes I am sorry.
When I do git commit, it prints the following message:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... /c/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/atom/bin/../app- 
1.44.0/resources/cli/atom.sh: line 23: cmd.exe: command not found
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

I am assuming it is to do with `cmd.exe` written in atom.sh file, but I am not sure, I tried reinstalling atom and git but nothing. And i did

```
git config --global code.editor "atom --wait"
```

I also tried replacing "atom" with its actual directory path, then it says:

```
Waiting for your editor to close the file...
and says aborted due to empty commit message, then opens atom editor.
```

Sorry if it is a bit confusing question, I have been stuck on this for so long.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like a $PATH issue. Did you set its path correctly or was it working at some point?

Comment: It was never working, first time i used git commit. What path should i do it to, atom.exe or what , and do I change it with the git config method?

Comment: Why is a sh file referencing cmd.exe? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, I can post a screenshot of the atom.sh if you want

Comment: Is there a space before the `.editor` ? if do remove it and try again

Comment: @CodeWizard no space before .editor

Comment: @aydinugur What do i set the path to, I see like 3 different paths for atom.exe tried them all, idk if theres more or if i should path to something else

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: @dan1st It just says %PATH% when i type that

Comment: @SafeRehman did you execute that in cmd? How did you start cmd? What is the output of `set`?

Comment: @dan1st No I executed in git bash. Set just gives a really really long output

Comment: In git bash, the command would be `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Does it work if you commit in `cmd`?

Comment: @dan1st the echo $PATH gives a few different paths: **/c/Users/Bob/bin:/c/Users/Bob/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.44.0/app-1.44** is one of them and also when i am in cmd it doesnt let me cd into any folder for some reason

Comment: Can you edit your question and add all paths?

Comment: Is `System32` in the paths?

Comment: In cmd, `system32` is in the path, and path doesnt change even if i cd, all paths when i type `echo $PATH` are: **/c/Users/Bob/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Bob/bin:/c/Users/Bob/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.44.0/app-1.44:/cmd:/c/Users/Bob/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Bob/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl**

Comment: Try `PATH=/c/Windows/System32:$PATH`...

Answer (score 1):

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55877301/6309), make sure to re-launch Atom with a simplified but complete PATH.

It needs to include Microsoft Windows path.
Open a CMD, and type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

set PATH=%LOCALAPPDATA%\atom\bin;%PATH%
```

Launch Atom from that CMD windows. And you can switch to git bash if you want. But only after having a proper PATH in a CMD. Not before.

See if the error message persists then.

---

The [OP Safe Rehman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12948549/safe-rehman) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362949/when-i-git-commit-cmd-exe-not-found/60370203#comment106812233_60370203):

> I tried [dan1sts method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362949/when-i-git-commit-cmd-exe-not-found/60370203#comment106792876_60362949)
>
> ```
> export PATH=/c/Windows/System32:$PATH
> ```
>
> and when I enter atom in git bash it opens finally.

Regarding the IDE Atom, check your [Git integration](https://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html#commit-editor):

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

Comment: @dan1st So simple! Thank you. I have fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @dan1st the point of my answer is to fix the PATH first, *then* you can switch to git bash if you want. Typing bash will get you there. But with a proper path.

Comment: Lol you guys seem so experienced in this ill try what you said thanks a lot :)

Comment: @VonC I entered the code you said in cmd then in bash i typed atom and same error, cmd.exe not found and the path is the same, maybe I did something wrong in cmd, oh and it opens when i type atom in cmd

Comment: @SafeRehman Do you get contents when typing (in CMD) `dir %LOCALAPPDATA%\atom\bin`?

Comment: @SafeRehman Did you replace `set GH=C:\path\to\git` by the actual path to your current git (you can see it by typing `where git` in a new CMD)?

Comment: @dan1st @VonC I tried dan1sts method `PATH=/c/Windows/System32:$PATH` and when i enter `atom` in git bash it opens finally, but git commit gives error still: `hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn C:UsersBobAppDataLocalatomapp-1.44.0atom.exe: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'C:UsersBobAppDataLocalatomapp-1.44.0atom.exe'
`

Comment: @SafeRehman Do you open bash by typing `bash` in the CMD where you just set the PATH?

Comment: @VonC says unknown command when i type `bash` let me try your other suggestions

Comment: @SafeRehman OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC `where git` gives error in cmd, but I think i can ifnd in program files, and `dir %LOCALAPPDATA%\atom\bin` does give contents

Comment: @SafeRehman What did you use as path for Git then, in the line `set GH=C:\path\to\git`?

Comment: @VonC i think i found the git folder and typed `set GH=C:\Program Files\Git`, typed `bash` in cmd and then `atom` which opened but `commit` still not working

Comment: @SafeRehman I have edited my answer to address the Atom part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208436/discussion-between-safe-rehman-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, It was resolved when I added the "%SystemRoot%\system32" value to the "Path" variable in the Environmental variable.

Answer (score -1):

@dan1sts method work!!!! I have tried so many methods, thanks god, let me try to make a summary here.

Step 1: Ensure you have added the PATH into system variables.

1. Search variables from 'Start', click 'Edict the system
   environment variables'
2. Click 'Environment Variables'
3. Under the 'System Variables', Select 'Path' and Click 'Edit'
4. Check if you have these two Path, if not, add them and click 'OK'

   - 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin;'
   - 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\atom\bin' (XXX is your windows user name)

Once you done it, re-open the git bash, type

```
which atom
```

you will see

'/c/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom'

Step 2: Then you could simply type

```
export PATH=/c/Windows/System32:$PATH
```

on the Git Bash.

And finally type

```
atom .
```

it works to me!!!!!