# Unable to connect to tfs server from Visual studio 2019 though the server is accessible from browser

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2019

I need to access tfs server from visual studio. I was able to access from corporate network, but once I'm on open network, I'm unable to connect. I'm able to access the tfs url from the browser, though the browser from visual studio gave an error page saying "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

Below is the screenshot of the error when I'm trying to push the code changes made on the branch to the server. I'm unable to push or fetch at this point. This is an issue on open network (wifi from home), but when I connect from office, it works fine. I don't have any VPN and my other colleagues don't face this issue at all when they work from home and they don't use any VPN. Initially I got the error message saying "Unable to get local issuer certificate", I used "git config --global http.sslVerify false" then I get the authentication failed message as shown the below screenshot. I gave the same credentials while I access the tfs server from browser in Visual studio, but it fails.

Below is the content from git config.

```
[user]
    name = <name>
    email = <email>
[http]
    sslbackend = openssl
    sslVerify = false
```

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Do you mean you can not connect to TFS at all from VS using open network? Do you use the same client machine? Could you try with another client machine?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is related to the "Warning" you see:

```
has a dubious owner (unknown).
For security reason, it is therefore ignored
To fix this, please transfer it to an administrator
```

[This thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/697976/git-failing-with-unknown-author.html) suggests as a workaround to create the file `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`

But that [won't always be enough](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/710486/faild-to-push-or-sync-to-azuredevops-with-vs-2019.html).

I would recommend, for testing, to unzip a [portable version of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (in `C:\mygit` for instance) while you are using wifi form home.
And setup in a CMD session a simplified PATH ([as I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370203/6309)).
Then launch [from that same CMD session Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/973561/6309), in order for that IDE to inherit from your simplified PATH which would point to the portable Git.
And see if the issue persists the?